# Data accessible from all Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to have a Map accessible to all the Servlets in a web server?

Can I do something as simple as extending a Servlet from all the servlet that has a static Map?

I just want for a servlet to do a search, fill the map structure and from that point on all the Servlets can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like [Session Variables](http://www.javadb.com/get-and-set-session-variables-in-a-servlet)?

Comment: Probably better than all the servlet instance having access to it...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Servlets arent inherently thread safe, so be careful about using static variables. If you are never going to alter these variables i.e if they are CONSTANTS then using static variables is fine.

Consider using session variables as suggested above, but that is subject to whether all your servlets are called within the same session.

You may also create an application cache and use data from it.

Comment: Will there be problems of multiple access like race conditions if I use the session variables?

Comment: @doubter Only possible if you create multiple threads for the same session (i.e. user) - and not very likely.